# python keep-alive connection and download image

Tags: python

I need download image from site by python, but this image changed every one second.
Is it possible:
- to set python connection [keep-alive]
- download image; sleep 1.5; download image; sleep 1.5; download image; sleep 1.5;
- close connection

I mean doesn't create connection to site every 1.5 sec use one keep-alive connection. And close connection at the end of the script (after 15 sec for example). Be sure that connection was closed.

If you have ideas how to do it, please show me example. Thanks!

Comment: Try this library - http://www.python-requests.org/ - documentation should cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) with some optional flags:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg',stream=True)
print r.headers['last-modified']
```

Has the file creation time as the output:

```
Thu, 03 Oct 2013 23:15:52 GMT
```

We use the 'stream=True' flag, with [this description](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/), because:

> At this point only the response headers have been downloaded and the connection remains open, hence allowing us to make content retrieval conditional

You can then check to see if the new file timestamp is updated from the old one, and then download only if the file is updated. To download the file, use r.content:

```
image = r.content
```

Here is a working code:

```
import requests
import time
oldtime = ''
for i in xrange(100):
    r = requests.get(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg',stream=True)
    newtime = r.headers['last-modified']
    if newtime != oldtime:
        image = r.content
        oldtime = newtime
    # you can put your time.sleep() statement here, but it is not necessary
```

Comment: Perfectly code, thanks! But should I add this line at the end of code? requests.get(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg', headers={'Connection':'close'})

Comment: It's not required, as the connection will close when the program stops. If you wanted to explicity close and reopen the connection, then you would want to include it.